# Rails, my stylesheet disappears magically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

Ok I just started a rails project...when i initially load the page it's styled as it's supposed to be.  Without changing any code when I refresh the stylesheet disappears.  I figured maybe it was a html/css error, but then if i close my browser and reopen it the page shows up fine again.  So it's not that.  I'm in dev mode so I don't think it's a cache issue. It happens in both firefox and chromium.

Comment: it appears this is the culprit..weird that it doesn't happen every time a refresh takes place
Referer -> /stylesheets/master.css?1276496528
[2010-06-14 03:19:10] ERROR NoMethodError: private method `gsub!' called for #<Class:0xb673bca0>
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/htmlutils.rb:16:in `escape'

Comment: Sound like it's inside webrick. I'd just install mongrel and see if it works.

Comment: I'm getting this error also; Good question therefore! Running Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.2.3. Running on windows and a Ubuntu install. Both do the same thing!!! I'm going to try and use Mongrel, but it is sure inconvenient to have to install something else when Webrick is there ready to be used... This issue make it practically unusable... I've found a couple of other instances of people having this issue, yet without answers. Question is that if it is so uncommon a problem (or it appears to be) then why are we having this issue and not everyone else?

Comment: hmm ok i'll give mongrel a try...i'd left the project alone but that's a good idea.

Comment: Switching to mongrel did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Just give Mongrel or Thin a try